# What am I doing wrong with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I recently discovered angularJS and have been trying to learn it, so I copied the simple todo tutorial into a yeoman generator angular app which happened to work just fine. However when I tried to write my own version, I cannot get the data to update automatically.

My HTML:

```
<div class="hero-unit">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="p in phones">{{p.name}} - {{p.snippet}}</li>
</ul>
  <a href="#" ng-click="addPhone()">click me</a>
</div>
```

My main.js

```
'use strict';
```

angular.module('ngApp')
  .controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {

```
$scope.phones = [
    {name: "Nexus S",
     snippet: "Fast just got faster with Nexus S."},
    {name: "Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi",
     snippet: "The Next, Next Generation tablet."},
    {name: "MOTOROLA XOOM™",
     snippet: "The Next, Next Generation tablet."}
  ];

 $scope.addPhone = function()
 {
    console.log('clicked');
    $scope.phones.push({
        name: "iPhone 5",
        snippet: "Awesome phone man"
    });
 };
});
```

I have not modified my app.js yet but here it is just in case:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ngApp', [])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help before I lose my mind. I'm sure it's something extremely simple that I am over looking. However when I click the link the item does not add itself to the list. However on initial load the list loads just fine.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the "clicked" does get logged to console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the parameter list as the 2nd parameter of `angular.module()`function, just change it from

```
angular.module('ngApp')
```

to

```
angular.module('ngApp', [])
```

<kbd>**[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H6CTb/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, but it still fails to work on my computer. I am using grunt, and the example from the angularjs site worked just fine... am I going crazy?

Comment: @user2554434 I updated the demo. Try use the same exactly angular module instance for registering both controller and routing.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. The only thing that ended up fixing the problem was removing href="#" from the a attribute. Is there any specific reason this was preventing it from working? I want to learn for the future to avoid this mistake again. Thank you none the less.

Comment: Yes, href is not using angularjs's routing scope and should always be set empty.